# How to extract information from a pivot table to populate a column in another table

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

Address information once stored in hierarchical production database, Patient table as TempStreetAddr1, TempStreetAddr2, TempCity, TempState, TempZip or Next of Kin (NOK) address, or Primary Care (PC) address and etc...  So there was a column for each address field for every type of address one can imagine a patient having.

Data is being extracted from that production database to SQL BI Report database where they split the Patient table and added a Address table which I'm told is a pivot table.  (I know nothing about pivot tables)  I now need to retrieve the data to it's original form so my query needs to look at this Address table with columns below and come up with TempAddress columns.  The column AddressType defines if it's a Temp, PC, or NOK.  The PatientSID is the identifier to join Patient and PatientAddress.  Is it possible to do this easily? How?

I'm a SQL DBA and not that great a developer but our developer contract is stalled and I'm trying to assist management.  Would appreciate help like code example or something.

I would like to transform along these lines; with each different AddressType I need to generate columns as shown in the two IF statements. 
--SQL 2012

```
If AddressType = 'Temporary' then StreetAddress1 as TempStreetAddr1, City as TempCity, State as TempState 

if AddressType = 'NOK' then StreeAddress1 as NokStreetAddr1, City as NOKCity, State as NOKState

  ,[PatientSID]
  ,[PatientIEN]
  ,[Sta3n]
  ,[OrdinalNumber]
  ,[AddressType]
  ,[NameOfContact]
  ,[StreetAddress1]
  ,[StreetAddress2]
  ,[StreetAddress3]
  ,[City]
  ,[County]
  ,[StateSID]
  ,[State]
  ,[Zip]
  ,[Zip4]
  ,[Province]
  ,[PostalCode]
  ,[Country]
  ,[Phone]
  ,[PhoneWork]
```

I can do it like this but this method really blows.  Surely there is a slicker way.

```
  Select
  p.GIVEN_NM, pa.addresstype,
  case pa.Addresstype
        when 'Temporary' then pa.StreetAddress1 
  END TempStreet1,
    case pa.Addresstype
        when 'Temporary' then pa.City 
  END TempCity,
    case pa.Addresstype
        when 'Temporary' then pa.State 
  END TempState,
    case pa.Addresstype
        when 'Temporary' then pa.Zip
  END TempZip,
    case pa.Addresstype
        when 'Next Of Kin' then pa.StreetAddress1 
  END NOKStreet1,
    case pa.Addresstype
        when 'Next Of Kin' then pa.City 
  END NOKCity,
    case pa.Addresstype
        when 'Next Of Kin' then pa.State 
  END NOKState,
    case pa.Addresstype
        when 'Next Of Kin' then pa.Zip
  END NOKZip

  FROM V5DW_vw.dbo.Patient P
  join [SPV].[SPatient].[SPatientAddress] pa 
  on p.PatientSID = pa.PatientSID
  where pa.AddressType in ('Next Of Kin','Temporary')
```

Comment: It is not clear how you want to transform the data, can you please add some sample data fro the temp addresses data and how do you want to transform it.

Comment: You don't state what version of SQL Server you are using, but if you are using 2005 or later, you might be able to use the [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)  function.

Comment: SQL 2012

    If AddressType = 'Temporary' then StreetAddress1 as TempStreetAddr1, City as TempCity, State as TempState

    if AddressType = 'NOK' then StreeAddress1 as NokStreetAddr1, City as NOKCity, State as NOKState

If Unpivot is the path, I need an example.  I looked at it before posting this question and really don't see how it would come into play in this situation.

Comment: The problem with using a case statement for each column desired is I get a separate row for each AddressType but what I really need is 1 row of data per patient with all the various address columns.